# Saving file in Eclipse runtime instance workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, resources

I have a plug-in project and custom command which gets file by clickin right click. My algorithm takes docx file and converts it to EMF model instance file(.xmi). The problem is typical resource saving is not working.  I want to save file, which is created runtime, in same directory with input file.

The java class below is my command handler class. At **Product p = Docx2ReqModelConverter.Convert(document);** line, I use my imported project class to parse document and convert it. It gives me the root element object of ecore model.

I just want to create a xmi file and save it in runtime eclipse.

```
public class ConvertHandler extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    XWPFDocument document = null;
    // Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event);
    ISelection sel = HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelection(event);
    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) sel;


    Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();

    if(firstElement instanceof IFile){

        IFile ifile = (IFile) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(firstElement, IFile.class);

        if (ifile == null) {
            if (firstElement instanceof IAdaptable) {
                ifile = (IFile) ((IAdaptable) firstElement).getAdapter(IFile.class);
            }
        }

        if (ifile != null) {

            File f = ifile.getLocation().toFile();
            try {


                document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(f));                    

                Product p = Docx2ReqModelConverter.Convert(document);
                createXMIFile(p);

                //Product p = Docx2ReqModelConverter.Convert(f);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }
    return null;

}

/**
 * Saves the model instance and writes it to xmi file
 * 
 * @param product
 */
private static Resource createXMIFile(Product product) {

    ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();

    // Register XML Factory implementation using xmi extension
    resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(
            "xmi", new  XMLResourceFactoryImpl());


    // Create empty resource with the given URI
    Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI("Testing/ReqModel.xmi"));


    // Add Product to contents list of the resource 

    resource.getContents().add(product);

    try{

        // Save the resource    
        resource.save(null);


    }catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resource;
}
```

}

Any comments and suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Not working how? What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: nothing happens. *createXMI()* is actually working on development enviroment. but in runtime eclipse instance(I mean when I started my plugin as eclipse app), file not created. I did print the resource object and content is OK.

Comment: It looks like you are using a file path relative to the current directory - which may not be what you think it is. Try specifying a full file path. If you are creating the file in the workspace you will need to refresh the folder as well.

Comment: OK. I guess you mean <IFile object>.getLocation().toString(). I will try. thanks